# Visual Studio Successfully Using Shared Project wwwroot Files on Publish but not on Build/Run

Tags: shared-project

#### The Background

I'm working in Visual Studio 2019. I have a C# Web APP Razor Pages project which references several C# Class Projects and one C# Shared Project for files common across several other related Web App projects.

#### The Problem

When I *publish* the web app project to my local or a remote IIS instance, no problem, the shared project files, all of them, are present and accounted for and work as expected.

However, when I "just" *build/run* then view it in the browser, the shared project Helper and Pages are as expected, but the shared project wwwroot files are all missing in action.

#### The Want

I could, but do not wish to *have* to, publish locally every single time I need to see / troubleshoot anything that's in the shared project, so ...

I would like to find a way for the shared project wwwroot folder assets to be useable on *Build/Run* -AND- to be able to do it in such as way as to not to adversely impact the *Publish* process in which it is currently working as expected.

#### The Deets

The example folder structure for the relevant projects (probably tmi but detailed enough that if I have to do soemthing with paths from one project to the other, these relative paths would be correct enough for an example to be made) ...

---

- inetpub

  - wwwroot

    - MyNameSoftware

      - wwwroot <-- all wwwroot files from both web app and shared projects end up here on *Publish*, yay

---

- MyName

  - **MyName.Common.Domain**

    - MyName.Common.Domain.csproj file

      - various folders and sub-folders with classes
  - **MyName.Common.Presentation.Web**

    - MyName.Common.Presentation.Web.shproj file
    - Helpers <-- works fine
    - Pages <-- works fine
    - **wwwroot** <--- these files are available on *Publish* but NOT on *Build/Run*
  - **aContainerFolder**

    - other irrelevant stuff and things
    - **MyName.Software**

      - MyName.Software.sln
      - Various other MyName.Software.{Purpose} folders for related projects included in solution
      - **MyName.Software.Web**

        - various other folders and sub-folders
        - **wwwroot** <-- these files are available as expected on both *Build/Run* and *Publish*
        - MyName.Software.Web.csproj file

---

#### Where to go from here

As I was laying out what I'd tried and the questions I had, some things fell into place. Love the process, hate the pre-process hair-pulling. So I've answered my own question here, but will go ahead and post this so I can refer back to it later and so maybe it will help someone else keep a few hairs. Also, if there are other ways to do this, bring 'em on -- always good to consider alternatives. :0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After research and putting bits and pieces together...

... the following is working for me on *Build/Run* and on *Publish* (be it via right-click-project-select-publish or via command line msbuild w/ deploy on build).

---

(1) store files destined for wwwroot in another folder, say, _wwwroot, and adjust the project files so they don't get published directly:

web app project's .csproj:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="_wwwroot\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

shared project's .projitems (note the absence here of CopyToPublishDirectory or CopyToOutputDirectory tags):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)_wwwroot\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

(2) add build events to the web app project

a pre-build event to remove everything in the web app project's wwwroot folder (so each build starts with a clean slate)

```
  rd /s /q "$(ProjectDir)wwwroot"
```

and 2 post-build events in each web app project

```
 xcopy /E /Y /I "$(ProjectDir)_wwwroot" "$(ProjectDir)wwwroot"
 xcopy /E /Y /I "$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\MyName.Common.Presentation.Web\_wwwroot" "$(ProjectDir)wwwroot"
```

(3) set each web app project's wwwroot to be ignored on check-in to source control since the _wwwroot folders will be checked-in and will be considered the source of record

(4) reference everything that *will* be in the wwwroot folder normally, just as if they are always there since they will be present in wwwroot when needed

---